# Sending a JSON POST request via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, backbone.js

I'm using POST to submit data to the server, this error appears in the console:

> POST localhost/myProject/webapp/setAccount 400 (Required String parameter 'accountID' is not present)

The user will select from a combo box an account ID and this is what should be passed in the post.

Here is my code:

```
accountSelected: function () {

 var accountSelected = $("#accountcombobox").val();
 console.log("Selected Account: " + accountSelected);
     var myUrl = "webapp/setAccount";

     $.ajax({
         url: myUrl,
         type: "POST",
         data: accountSelected,
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json"
            })
         .done(function (data) {
         console.log("Response " + JSON.stringify(data));
         })
        }
```

The first console.log shows the selected account ID as expected so i know the value is correct.  I want to pass this value to the POST request, which is what i thought i was doing but cannot seem to get it to work.

EDIT

Thanks for the responses but none of the answers seem to be working for me, still the same error.

I'm also using Marionette and Backbone, could this effect it?

Comment: missing semicolon and already getting value has json then no neet to stringify it

Comment: What does the first console.log actually output? Can you put your code on JSFiddle?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
data:{ accountSelected: accountSelected},
```

AND,

```
console.log("Response " + data); //removed JSON.stringify
```

in webapp/setAccount,

```
 echo  $_POST['accountSelected'];
```

Comment: None of these are working for me - same error, i'm also using Backbone.js and Marionette, is this something that could be effecting it?

Answer (score -2):

Your data should be in key: value form, so:

Edit: changed to success

```
$.ajax({
         url: myUrl,
         type: "POST",
         data:{
             accountID: accountSelected
         },
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         success: function(data)
         {
                console.log("Response " +data.accountSelected);
         }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting the exact same error, anything else i could try?

Comment: Try the code in my edit (remove the .done bit) and see what happens

Comment: Same error i'm afraid - i'm using Backbone and Marionette - could that be causing issues?

If i change:
    data:{accountID:"Full"}

i no longer get the error - but obviously it needs to be linked to the combo box

Comment: No. With `contentType: "application/json"` `data` needs to be a string of JSON, not an object.

Answer (score -2):

```
accountSelected: function () {

 var accountSelected = $("#accountcombobox").val();
 console.log("Selected Account: " + accountSelected);
     var myUrl = "webapp/setAccount";

     $.ajax({
         url: myUrl,
         type: "POST",
         data: "accountID="+accountSelected,
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         success: function(result) {
             console.log("Response " + JSON.stringify(result));
          },
      error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('textStatus ' + textStatus);
        alert('errorThrown ' + errorThrown);
       }

          });
        }
```

Comment: `"accountID="+accountSelected,` is (or would be if you applied proper escaping) URL encoded data. It doesn't match `contentType: "application/json",`.

Comment: @Quentin you commented for few answers that they are incorrect. Can you provide correct answer please? Coz it's not workign for me too :(

Comment: @BogdanMart — Do you see the big yellow "This question already has an answer" box at the top? Click the link.

Answer (score -3):

No need to use JSON.stringify coz you already mentioned dataType:'json' so try this

```
$.ajax({
     url: myUrl,
     type: "POST",
     data: { accountSelected: accountSelected},
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json"
        })
     .done(function (data) {
     console.log("Response " +data.accountSelected);
     });
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the JQuery documentation states that 'dataType' is the server's expected return type.